# Summing particular items of a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to solve this using linq.  Perhaps my syntax is off.

Given the following object:

```
Data
-----------
string type  
string number  
string value
```

I have an `IEnumerable<Data>` objects.  I basically want to return 1 Data object with the values summed up (type and number in this case would be identical).

Initially I thought this was a case for the `Aggregate()` function but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

Here is what I had although I understand it is incorrect:

```
var results = thisData.Aggregate(new Data(), (data, item) => { item.value?? });
```

Thanks!

**Update**
I think I may have not asked my question very well.  At the end of this process I only want 1 record containing type, number and a summed (or aggregate) value.  Is there a simple elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: if there is only one aggregate (as opposed to a group) what is the point of having a type and a number? Which type or number from the collection would you want to have in that record?

Comment: @BrokenGlass the type and number in this specific instance will be the same.

Comment: Then @Femaref's answer should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = thisData.Aggregate(new Data() 
                                 { 
                                   type = thisData.First().type, 
                                   number = thisData.First().number 
                                 } , (data, item) => data.value += item.value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var results = thisData.Sum( d => int.Parse(d.value) );
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var results = thisData.Aggregate( 0, (seed, d) => seed + int.Parse(d.value) );
```

That is, thinking that you only want to add up the values (and that they are integers of course).

Aggregating only makes sense when your types form a [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) (in a mathematical sense) regarding your desired operation (e.g. sum). Having a group guarantees you a neutral element (0) and an operation (+) that you can use.

Strings form a group with `{"", +}`, integers form a group with `{0, +}`, and `{1, *}`.

Comment: This might work for number but what if type is not an integer to start with?

Comment: Aggregating only makes sense when your types form a group (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), so you have a neutral element (0) and an operation (+) which aggregate uses. Strings form a group with the "" and concatenation, integers form a group with 0 and +, or 1 and *.